# Show that in general $\partial\{x\in T : f(x)>0\}\neq \{x\in T:f(x)=0\}$

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise in my textbook:

Let $f: T\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function on $T$. Show that in general $$\partial\{x\in T : f(x)>0\}\neq \{x\in T:f(x)=0\}$$

The answer in my book gives the following:

Take $T=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$. $f(x)=x$ for $x>0$.

I understand why this is true. What if for example I have the following function $f(x)=1 \forall x\in T=\mathbb{R}$. Would that also be valid?

Comment: What is $f(0)$ in the book's answer?

Comment: In general, if $f$ is continuous,  one has that $\partial f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(\partial A)$. For functions between metric spaces one can use sequences to provide a proof of this fact. For general Hausdorff spaces, one can use nets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T=\mathbb R$  and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto 1$ is your function, then $$\{x\in\mathbb R: f(x)>0\}=\mathbb R\Longrightarrow\partial\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)>0\}=\emptyset$$ and $$\{x\in T:f(x)=0\}=\emptyset$$ as well. So both sets are empty and therefore equal, thus not a valid counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

- Here is a counterexample (similar yo your textbook's): consider the function $f(x)=x^+=\max(x,0)$ on the real line. Then $\partial f^{-1}(0,\infty)=\partial (0,\infty)=\{0\}$ while $f^{-1}(\partial(0,\infty))=f^{-1}(\{0\})=(-\infty,0]$. Hence
  $$\partial f^{-1}(0,\infty)\subset f^{-1}\big(\partial(0,\infty)\big)=f^{-1}(\{0\})$$
- In general, for continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between Hausdorff spaces, $\partial f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(\partial A)$.

To illustrate this, here is a proof when the case where $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces:

If $x\in \partial f^{-1}(A)=\overline{f^{-1}(A)}\cap\overline{(X\setminus f^{-1}(A))}$,  then there are sequences $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset f^{-1}(A)$ and $\{y_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset X\setminus f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(Y\setminus A)$ such that $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}x$ and $y_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}x$. If $f$ is continuous, then
$f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ and $f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ and so
$f(x)\in \overline{f(A)}$ and $f(x)\in\overline{Y\setminus A}$, that is, $f(x)\in\partial A$. Consequently, $x\in f^{-1}(A)$. This shows that $$\partial f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(\partial A)$$

For general Hausdorff spaces, one may use nets (instead of sequences). The proof then becomes similar.